# Guard not triggering when using WSL with /mnt/c windows volume

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, guard

I'm using Guard inside a docker container, that is watching a mounted docker volume `/docs/app`.

I'm running this container on Windows via WSL2. I find that if I map this docker vol to a path under `/home/`, which is a linux file system, then it works just fine.

But if I map it to a path under `/mnt/c/Users/`, which is a Windows file system, then it fails to detect any file changes.

Anyone have a theory as to what might be going on? Does Guard rely on some file system features that are not exposed on mounted windows volumes?